# How to interact with inputs inside a modal

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a pop up modal when the page loads. There are two ways: changing in CSS the opacity to 1 or with jQuery.

```css
.popupmodal{
    display: block;
    line-height: 250%;
    font-size: 2.5vh;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    z-index: 99999;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.popupmodal:target{
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}

.popupmodal > div{
    height: auto;
    width: 50%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10% auto;
    padding: 3% 2% 3% 2%;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 1%;
}

.popup-modal-quest > div{
    background-color: transparent;
    margin: 1% auto;
    height: 60vh;
}
}
```

```html
<!-- just to be sure the modal is working -->
<!-- <a href="#quest-modal" class="abrir-modal">You have a new quest. Click here to see.</a> -->

<p>TRY TO SELECT THIS TEXT</p>

<div id="quest-modal" class="popupmodal popup-modal-quest">
        <div class="modal-quest">
            <img src="img/wooden-warning.png">
            <div class="btns-quest">
                <a href="#open-modal"><input type="button" value="Accept quest" class="btn-quest"></a>
                <a href="#go-back-page"><input type="button" value="Do not accept quest" class="btn-quest"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Both ways make the modal appear when the document loads. However, I can not interact with the inputs inside it. When I click on the button, all the modal and its content become like *static*.

I started learning JS and jQuery recently, so I would like to know if the solution needs some code of these.

Comment: Try this delete `pointer-events: none;` in `.popupmodal` class

Comment: Please don't post links to your code that is posted in other questions that you've asked or 3rd party sites as those links can die over time, making your question meaningless. Always include the relevant code right in your question, preferably as a Stack Snippet, so we can run it right here. No need for CodePen.

Answer (score 0):

The `pointer-events:none` setting in your CSS is doing exactly what it's supposed to do - - make it so the mouse pointer does not interact with anything. So, remove that.

Also, the vendor prefixed CSS is not needed as CSS transitions have been standard for almost a decade now.

```css
.popupmodal{
    display: block;
    line-height: 250%;
    font-size: 2.5vh;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    z-index: 99999;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
}

.popupmodal:target{
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}

.popupmodal > div{
    height: auto;
    width: 50%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10% auto;
    padding: 3% 2% 3% 2%;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 1%;
}

.popup-modal-quest > div{
    background-color: transparent;
    margin: 1% auto;
    height: 60vh;
}
}
```

```html
<!-- just to be sure the modal is working -->
<!-- <a href="#quest-modal" class="abrir-modal">You have a new quest. Click here to see.</a> -->

<p>TRY TO SELECT THIS TEXT</p>

<div id="quest-modal" class="popupmodal popup-modal-quest">
        <div class="modal-quest">
            <img src="img/wooden-warning.png">
            <div class="btns-quest">
                <a href="#open-modal"><input type="button" value="Accept quest" class="btn-quest"></a>
                <a href="#go-back-page"><input type="button" value="Do not accept quest" class="btn-quest"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Ok, the buttons became clickable but do not work. It is supposed to close the modal and come back to the page behind it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove  `pointer-events: none;` from `.popupmodal{}`

Comment: the button became clickable but the <a> property stopped working

Comment: <input type="button" class="button_active" onclick="location.href='1.html';" />

Answer (score 0):

Add some javascript code to do some stuff when you click the button. Also add id="" to each button.

```
const acceptBtn = document.getElementById("acceptBtn");
const doNotAcceptBtn = document.getElementById("doNotAcceptBtn");

acceptBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    /*
     when accept button is clicked, do some stuff
     */
});

doNotAcceptBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    /*
     when doNotAcceptBtn is clicked, do some stuff
     */
});
```